# Superimpose transparent logo on top of wiper which moves on top of background image

Tags: html

I have a background image in the home page of my website. I have put a wiper on top of it which moves from left to right when the page is scrolled down. I have used linear gradient. Can I superimpose a transparent part of my logo on the wiper, so that it also moves when the page is scrolled?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: css z-index property

Comment: I have used Linear Gradient to create the Wiper and now, I am able to display a text in my Wiper. But, I need to display a Image on the wiper. Is that possible?

Comment: I need to display Image instead of text in below code :
        <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
          <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#224897" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
          <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#ea242b" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
          <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#224897" stop-opacity="1"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
      <g transform="scale(30.9) translate(0,0)"> 
        <circle cx="60" cy="100" r="50" fill="url(#grad1)"/>
        <Text fill="#ffffff" font-size="3" font-family="Verdana" x="50" y="70">Hi</text>